# Storing a version in an integer

Tags: integer, versioning

So I was thinking of a way to store an entire version string inside an integer, and be able to effectively compare it. I know there are ways to compare versions using methods such as string splitting, but I'm curious to see if something like the following would be possible:

```
// version =   major << 16 | minor << 8 | revision
int version1 =     1 << 16 |     2 << 8 | 3        // 1.2.3
int version2 =     0 << 16 |    13 << 8 | 2        // 0.13.2
if(version1 > version2) { ... }                    // true
```

Is this a practical way to store versions and be able to easily compare them? Is there any particular advantage or disadvantage to doing it this way versus splitting and comparing strings?

Comment: Why not use a structure to store the version? Probably makes things a lot simpler

Comment: It will certainly work, but it may not be very OO. Just because the version can be represented as an int, perhaps doesn't mean it should. Another thing you have to consider is what happens when you have some field with a greater value than 255 or less than 0.

Comment: @Zymus Well, typically version numbers don't go below zero unless you're using a _really weird_ versioning format. I chose the max to be 255 because version numbers don't go that high normally, but it can be raised if necessary.

Comment: @DonkeyCore - They do especially the engineering version numbers when using continuous integration (like doing three or four builds per day)

Comment: @EdHeal 3 to 4 is a bit low in my experience :-)

Comment: @EdHeal Okay, so if I were to just increase the number that it is shifted by, to let's say 32 for the major and 16 for the minor, and I were to use a long int instead of an int (in terms of C), that would pretty much fix the problem, correct?

Comment: Why make a rod for your own back? Sooner or later you might run into the same problem and the worse thing is that you might not notice it. Just use a structure to store the values. In that way this problem will never occur

Comment: @EdHeal But then how could I, for example, send the version value to a remote location? I would have to send 3 ints with a structure, versus a single int. And the problem would be as likely of overflowing as if you were to use integers in a structure, because I am shifting 32 bits which is the maximum size of a normal int.

Comment: So why is sending 3 ints more difficult that sending one int? We are only talking a few extra bytes

Comment: @EdHeal Fair point, I guess. I suppose it shouldn't be too much trouble to simply use a structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think I'd recommend using an integer to store the version. I find that they're more often represented as strings, and parsed using something like regex. So I'd probably use that, especially if you'd like your code to be easily understood / interoperable with other developers.

That being said, I do see the benefit of using an integer to store a version. It could be made slightly more convenient by wrapping it in a class (this is in C++):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // std::boolalpha
#include <stdint.h> // uint64_t, uint16_t

// Class representing a version string
class Version {
    const static unsigned int field_size = 16;
    uint64_t version;  // 64 bits => largest field we can support is 16 bits
   public:
    Version(uint16_t major, uint16_t minor, uint16_t revision)
        : version((uint64_t)major << 2 * field_size | (uint64_t)minor << field_size | revision) {}

    // Implicit cast for integer-like operations
    operator uint64_t() const { return version; }

    // Output version string as major.minor.revision
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Version& v);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Version& v) {
    const uint16_t mask = (uint16_t)(-1);
    return (
        os << (v >> 2 * Version::field_size & mask) << "." 
           << (v >> Version::field_size & mask) << "." 
           << (v & mask)
    );
}


int main() {
    auto v0 = Version(0, 0, 5);
    auto v1 = Version(1, 2, 3);
    auto v2 = Version(2, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "v0: " << v0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v1: " << v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v2: " << v2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (v1 < v2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (v1 < v0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/** Output:

$ ./a.out 
v0: 0.0.5
v1: 1.2.3
v2: 2.0.0
true
false

*/
```

The trick here is to define the conversion to a 64 bit int. Then you get your desired behaviour mostly for free. I'd imagine this approach could be modified for other languages. If the language facilities don't support this kind of conversion, alternative approaches could be defining your own operator overloads, as well as functions for serializing / parsing versions. But then I doubt you'd be gaining much over the struct solution @Zymus mentioned.